# \citeauthor and \citeyear not working correct with multibib and natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, multibib

I have this minimal document (doc.tex):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{book}{References}
\bibpunct[; ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,~}

\begin{document}

Some senseless text with citation \citepbook{book}.
And another text with citation (\citeauthor{book}, \citeyear{book} and \citeauthor{book2}, \citeyear{book2}).


\bibliographystylebook{apalike2}
\bibliographybook{sourcesBook}

\end{document}
```

And this .bib file:

```
@Misc{book,
  author= {{Book}},
  year={2017},
}

@Misc{book2,
  author= {{Book 2}},
  year={2016}
}
```

When I generate the document now, I will get a failure for the second entry of the bib file. The log says:

> Package natbib Warning: Citation `book2' on page 1 undefined on input
>   line 13.

The output of the PDF looks like this:

[image]

Anyone an idea what is wrong here? I need the multibib because I have to generate a bibliography for books and online sources.

Comment: have you tried running bibtex-->pdflatex-->bibtex-->pdflatex?

Comment: Yes ... I run pdflatex multiple times before and after the bibtex command

Comment: When I look into the book.aux file I see only the `\citation{book}` and in the doc.aus file I see both `\citation{book}` and `\citation{book2}`

Comment: do you have .bib file with spaces in its name?

Comment: No, the bibfiles are named "sourceBook.bib" or "sourceOnline.bib", for example.

Comment: Are you able to compile the minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already noted in a comment to your own answer, you have to use one of the `multibib` variants of the usual cite commands before you can use `\citeyear` and `\citeauthor`, for which there is no `multibib` variant, unfortunately.

However, there *is* a `multibib` variant for the `\nocite` command, which technically causes a citation but is invisible. Thus, if `\citealpbook` is not an option, you can avoid adding additional useless citations and do this instead:

```
Some senseless text with citation \citepbook{book}. 
And another text with citation (\citeauthor{book}, \citeyear{book}
and \nocitebook{book2}\citeauthor{book2}, \citeyear{book2}).
```

Comment: Nice. +1 for this solution. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for my issue.

I that case the `natbib` command `\citealpbook{book2}` works for me. The result looks like I will need it:

[image]

In the document I now have:

```
Some senseless text with citation \citepbook{book}. 
And another text with citation (\citeauthor{book}, \citeyear{book}; \citealpbook{book2}, p. 7).
```

Comment: I also found out that you will need a "normal" cite anywhere before using `citeauthor and citeyear` if you are using multibib.